# How to hide [an error occurred while processing this directive] from webpage

Tags: php, html, error-handling

So I have a HTML webpage the is processing some php but above where it is showing the php results it shows: [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Since everything is working all I want to do is hide that line from showing up at all. Is there any type of javascript I can add that can just hide that text from showing up if it appears?

Here is my webpage: http://dirbmudcats.com/dev/teams-8u.html

Comment: What generates that error? Why can you not supress the error display there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getSet() in /homepages/17/d434399820/htdocs/dirbmudcats/dev/sitefiles/set.php on line 21
```

The function getSet() is not defined. Try to define it and then check

Comment: I have added a function to define getSet(): <? 
  $theSet = 72157625817984495;
  $flickr = getSet($theSet); ?> but then none of the image showed up at all

Comment: I am not really sure, its a php file that is running a decent amount of code, i just want a way to hide that error since it returns the correct Set already

Comment: sorry its this page: http://dirbmudcats.com/dev/sitefiles/sets.php, and when u click on the Set, that is the URL I am trying to pull in so this is the PHP URL i am trying include: http://dirbmudcats.com/dev/sitefiles/set.php?id=72157625817984495&title=Endara+Bachelor+Party

Comment: There is one prefix "@" which disable showing errors of fuction for example @getSet(); would show no error so try to put that @ beore some function or try to search the given string in your php

Comment: so you want to load that 1st link in your php file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25247/discussion-between-alpdog14-and-michael-ticho)